# Bean Creation Failing in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, cucumber, bdd

I'm trying to access classes from a `.jar` file within my Spring Boot application. Here's how I've declared the bean initialization in RtgsTestConfiguration:

```java
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class RtgsTestConfiguration {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RtgsTestConfiguration.class);

    @Bean
    @Scope("cucumber-glue")
    XmlToDocumentConverter xmlToDocumentConverter() {
        return new XmlToDocumentConverter();
    }
}
```

In my step definition file (`CommonSteps`), I've declared dependencies including `XmlToDocumentConverter`:

```java
public class CommonSteps extends BaseSteps {

    public CommonSteps(final RtgsConfigurationProperties configurationProperties,
                       final RtgsConfigurationService<Context> contextService,
                       final ContextWorld contextWorld,
                       final AuthenticationWorld authenticationWorld,
                       final RtgsConfigurationService<Jwt> jwtService,
                       final XmlToDocumentConverter xmlToDocumentConverter)
    {

        super(configurationProperties, contextWorld, xmlToDocumentConverter);
        this.contextService = contextService;
        this.authenticationWorld = authenticationWorld;
        this.jwtService = jwtService;
    }

    @And("I validate the response, ensuring all essential fields are correctly populated.")
    public void iValidateTheResponseEnsuringAllEssentialFieldsAreCorrectlyPopulated() {       xmlToDocumentConverter.convertXmlToDocumentPacs004(ResponseValidation.responseFileName);
    }
}
```

I'm encountering an issue with bean creation in my Spring Boot application. I have a `XmlToDocumentConverter` bean defined in my `RtgsTestConfiguration` class, and it's failing to instantiate with the following

```
error:org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xmlToDocumentConverter' defined in com.santander.api.framework.rtgs.configuration.RtgsTestConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.isbanuk.iso20022.common.utils.converter.XmlToDocumentConverter]: Factory method 'xmlToDocumentConverter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/xml/bind/JAXBException
```

It seems to be related to a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` for `jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException`. I've already included the necessary dependencies in my pom.xml file, but the issue persists.

I have added these dependencies

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I am using Java 17 in my system.

Comment: *I've already included the necessary dependencies*, clearly you haven't.  Version 3 is still using the old` javax.xml` namespace. Use the 4.x version instead. Even better, as you are using Spring Boot remove the `version` tag and spring boot will manage it for you.

Comment: First thanks for trying to solving. Yes I removed version, than I am getting following error "org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar: unknown was not found in maven2". But I tried 4.0.0 still I am getting Jax exception.

Comment: Are you using the `spring-boot-starter-parent` as a parent? That was my assumptions but judging from the error you aren't. Only changing the `jaxb-runtime` won't do a thing you need to change the API version as well.

Comment: I haven't provided the complete pom.xml file. I only mentioned those two dependencies (JAXB API and implementation) because they are related to the JAXBException error. Additionally, my project uses spring-boot-starter, spring-boot-starter-test, and spring-boot-starter-validation.

Comment: Well if you have a proper spring boot pom (with the parent as mentioned) Spring Boot should manage those versions. As that isn't happening you have not a proper Spring Boot pom hence you need to add the versions yourself (or add the parent).

Comment: Yes I added the latest version from maven repository. But still I am getting the same error that Jax exception.